# Type families for dummies

Tags: haskell

Could someone give a super simple (few line) example to get a basic understanding about what type families can be used for and what are they ?

The 2+2 kind of example of type families ?

Comment: Type families are not for dummies, unfortunately. Even Richard Eisenberg, a top GHC type system developer, finds some aspects a bit hard to pin down. However, I can try to show some basic things, I suppose.

Comment: @dfeuer: luckily there's a difference between grasping some simple examples of something, and properly pinning down all aspects of it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
{-# Language TypeFamilies, DataKinds, KindSignatures, GADTs, UndecidableInstances #-}

data Nat = Z | S Nat

type family Plus (x :: Nat) (y :: Nat) :: Nat where
  Plus 'Z y = y
  Plus ('S x) y = 'S (Plus x y)

data Vec :: Nat -> * -> * where
  Nil :: Vec 'Z a
  Cons :: a -> Vec n a -> Vec ('S n) a

append :: Vec m a -> Vec n a -> Vec (Plus m n) a
append Nil ys = ys
append (Cons x xs) ys = Cons x (append xs ys)
```

Note that many/most interesting applications of type families require `UndecidableInstances`. You should not be scared of this extension.

---

Another useful sort of type family is one associated with a class. For a really contrived example,

```
class Box b where
  type Elem b :: *
  elem :: b -> Elem b
```

An instance of `Box` is a type that something can be pulled out of. For instance,

```
instance Box (Identity x) where
  type Elem (Identity x) = x
  elem = runIdentity

instance Box Char where
  type Elem Char = String
  elem c = [c]
```

Now `elem (Identity 3) = 3` and `elem 'x' = "x"`.

You can also use type families to make weird skolem variables. This is best done in the as-yet-unreleased GHC 8.0.1, where it will look like

```
type family Any :: k where {}
```

`Any` is a peculiar type. It's uninhabited, it can't be (specifically) an instance of a class, and it's poly-kinded. This turns out to be really useful for certain purposes. This particular type is advertised as a safe target for `unsafeCoerce`, but `Data.Constraint.Forall` uses similar type families for more interesting purposes.

Comment: I don't quite understand the line : `Plus ('S x) y = 'S (Plus x y)`

Comment: @jhegedus, `'S` is the type constructor that `DataKinds` creates from the data constructor `S`. You can leave out the `'`, but its use is encouraged. That line says, essentially, `(1 + x) + y = 1 + (x + y)`.

Comment: So with type families I can have pattern matching and recursion on the type level ? Lifting pattern matching and recursion to type level ? So a type family is basically a fully blown function at the type level ?

Comment: @jhegedus, Up to a point, yes. The pattern matching, however, is done by type unification, so it doesn't always work quite the way you might expect. You can, for example, use the same type variable twice in the left-hand side. More annoyingly, sometimes GHC can't reduce a type far enough to match a pattern, leading to somewhat confusing errors and more confusing work-arounds. For example, if is used `Plus ('S m) n = Plus m ('S n)`, I'd have run into trouble defining `append`.

Comment: This was a pretty nice intro to type families in 5 min, thanks again !

Comment: Ahh, so in the second Box example, the return type of `elem` depends on the actual instance ? In this sense we use type families again to define a type level function ? Now the domain of that function (Elem b) is {Char, Identity a} . I wonder if the type of `elem` should be `b-> Elem b` ?

Comment: @jhegedus, that's what I meant.