# Function working on types instead of values

Tags: haskell, types

In Haskell, I want to make an association like:

```
-- Given types A, B, C, and X, Y, Z,
-- make some sort of manual association :
f A = X
f B = Y
f C = Z

-- Intended use (for example)
g :: a -> ... -> f a
```

I think its kind should be `* -> *`, which can be the kind of some constructors, but I don't know how to manually make associations...

**So, how do you create a function of types, ie a function which you give a type and the result is another type ?**

Comment: You are looking for type families. Cf. [*Type families for dummies*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34482540/2751851).

Comment: I need an extension for this ? Will it work if I try a compiler different than GHC ?

Comment: @Synxis Type families are pretty standard, as are a lot of extensions.  GHC is pretty much the only compiler out there for Haskell if you're targeting native (there is GHCJS for targeting the browser, and a handful of others).  You even hit it right on the nose when you said that you want to make an association between types, that's exactly what type families do.

Comment: Thank you then. If you make an answer I can accept it

Comment: @Synxis As a footnote to bheklilr's comment, GHCJS supports ["All type system extensions supported by GHC"](https://github.com/ghcjs/ghcjs).